# Change resolution of a image in ndarray format without changing dimensions in pixel

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, numpy-ndarray, nifti

In my specific case I have volumes in nifti format (CT images), which I convert to ndarray format in order to do a series of preprocessing operations. Among these I should decrease the resolution of this image if possible directly on an ndarray that represents a slice of this volume. Is it possible to do this without having to do it directly on the nifti format? I don't want to resize the image like for example to switch from a size of 512x512 to 320x320, I want to keep the same size by changing only the resolution.

Comment: You would reduce the resolution by applying a smoothing filter. I recommend Gaussian smoothing.

Comment: the resolution *is* the size. lowpassing may change the amount of information in the picture, but it's still the same resolution/size. -- what _exactly_ are your preprocessing operations and why do they want "decreased resolution"?